# Should I use a pointer when dealing with lists?

Tags: c++, qt, list, pointers, memory-management

Pointers should be used when an object should live longer, even when it goes out of scope, right?

Here I just create a Movie m; . It will be created on the stack and automatically deleted when it goes out of scope.

```
//In some header file
typedef struct{
Qstring name;
int id;
//...
} Movie ;


QList<Movie> movieList; //It's the same as the standard list of c++. 

//In a function somewhere else
void doSomething(/*...*/)
{
//Do something...
Movie m = { /* ... */ };
movieList.push_back( m );
}
```

A list takes a constant reference of type T as argument. So it's the address, right? But when `Movie m;` goes out of scope it will be deleted. Somehow the item in the list stays.

However, my question is should I use a pointer and create the `Movie m;` on the heap or is this fine? What is better style?

Comment: No problem here, `m` will be destroyed but you made a **copy** of it when you put it on the vector.

Comment: @john so lists, vectors etc. will copy the item?

Comment: Yes, always. You actually cannot use a vector or list unless the object can be copied.

Comment: I've just noticed you're taling about QT data structures not the standard ones. I *guess* they're the same.

Comment: @john i think u can use vector or list if ur object can be moved (and in the case of `list` i dont even think it has to be movable)

Comment: @john yeah, QList is almost the same. It has some more features though.

Comment: @Kal I'm sure you're right but that would be C++11 and I don't know anything about that.

Comment: Use std::shared_ptr? (or std::unique_ptr in special case). I mean list of shared ptrs of the objects.

Comment: Objects created on the stack do **not** get **deleted** when they go out of scope. They get **destroyed**. If you create an object with `new` you can **delete** it; that destroys the object **and** releases the memory that was allocated for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Pointers should be used when an object should live longer, even when it goes out of scope, right?"*

Although it is true that local objects with automatic storage duration are automatically destructed when the execution goes out of scope, it does not necessarily mean that dynamically allocated object would live longer.

In your application, you have global variable:

```
QList<Movie> movieList;
```

representing container that lives during the whole time of your program's execution.

> *"Somehow the item in the list stays"*

When you create an object of type `Movie` and push it into your container:

```
Movie m;
...
movieList.push_back(m);
```

the copy of this object is stored in the list. Copies are being created in different situations, mainly when you pass or return by value, yet in most of cases it will have no negative impact on performance of your program. There are many optimization techniques that your compiler will use to elide copies... sometimes so effectively that passing/returning by value might become even faster than passing by reference.

> "*should I use a pointer and create the `Movie m;` on the heap?*"

**NO!** Once you start allocating objects dynamically, you take the responsibility for memory management on yourself and many things might become far more complicated that they could be otherwise... including possible and very frequent (usually due to imperfections in error handling) problems with ***memory leaks***, problems with ***dangling pointers*** that might make you fall into the pits of ***undefined behavior*** and many other kinds of unpleasant stuff.

***Avoid dynamic memory allocation always when it is possible.*** Use objects with automatic storage duration, learn about [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and take delight in following it.

Comment: OTOH, I'd imagine an object representing a Movie could be quite large... e.g. a 2 hour movie might represent several gigabytes of data.  If that's the case, then making multiple copies of the Movie is something you'd probably want to avoid.  (for safety's sake, though, you'd want to some sort of smart-pointer class like QPointer or std::shared_ptr to manage the dynamically allocated Movie object safely)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: There are some situations when it really matters, that's why I wrote *"in most of cases it will have no negative impact on performance"*. There's more than enough of premature optimization already.